# Errors in classification problem using the ctree fucntion, found in party

Tags: r, algorithm

can you please help me solve this error: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Cl.thickness' not found
i checked the data, and all the attributes are the but somehow the predict function kicks out the clthickness variable. THe model i am testing is the decision tree model. all else is working fine just when i test i get this error

Comment: Hello Thomas, welcome to SO. Unfortunately there isn't much anyone can do here without a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is already a close vote on it. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide more information. The effort on your side will help attract good answers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.